# Krpano/Phonegap doesn't load videos

Tags: android, html, cordova, html5-video, krpano

im trying to get my (html5, webm, ogv)videos run on phonegap but it doesnt work, since im making a virtual tour via krpano the videoplayer plugins wont work as well.

any idea how to get the video loaded? maybe over a remote server? but what is the pathname?

this is my krpano code(cut down to whats neccesary), I only use phonegap to insert the xml file which does the rest, krpano has its own videoplayer which works well on desktop/html5. The error I get is "loading video failed" path should be correct since it works on desktop + the "posterurl" image gets loaded.

```html
  <plugin name="video1"
  url="%SWFPATH%/plugins/videoplayer.swf"
        alturl="%SWFPATH%/plugins/videoplayer.js"
        videourl="%SWFPATH%/luft.mp4"
  altvideourl="%SWFPATH%/luft.webm"
  posterurl="%SWFPATH%/dammbau.jpg"
        align="center" x="0" y="0"
        pausedonstart="true"
        volume="1.0"
        buffertime="0.8"
        updateeveryframe="true"
        onvideocomplete="removeplugin(video1)"
  onvideoready= "if(isphone,set(hotspot[video1].pausedonstart,true),set(hotspot[video1].pausedonstart,false));"
  onclick="togglepause();"
        />
   <hotspot name="video2" 
     url="%SWFPATH%/plugins/videoplayer.swf" 
     alturl="%SWFPATH%/plugins/videoplayer.js" 
     ath="227.4" atv="-29.9" distorted="true" rx="-19.75" ry="2.50" rz="-1.17" width="640" height="360" scale="0.577" 
     buffertime="0.1"
     directionalsound="false"
     ignoremetadata="false"
     iscomplete="true"
     isvideoready="true"
     loop="true"
     pausedonstart="false"
     posterurl="%SWFPATH%/dammbau.jpg"
     videourl="%SWFPATH%/dammbau.mp4"
     altvideourl="%SWFPATH%/dammbau.webm"
     volume="0"
     onclick="togglepause();"
     />
```

Comment: you probably access the root so use relative links

Comment: already tried out several different kinds of varieties, what is the relative links on a mobile when my videofile is stored in my rootfolder?

Comment: i've seen problems with phonegap dealing with root while relative links work

Comment: dont know how to use relative links at this, to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use krpano with Phonegap but used for a website for iOS, then had a same error "loading video failed". In my case, I just simply took "%SWFPATH%" off and worked. I'm still not really sure but I guess because iOS doesn't support SWF maybe?

Comment: i have video loading failed error in safari mac only .. could u please tell me how did u solved it .. thanks in advance